# How to handle unreadable shard file?

Tags: couchdb

I'm backing up my whole server (including virtual machines) periodically with `rsync`. Now there is something wrong with my harddisk and some files are not readable, including a file of CouchDB (message is obfuscated):

```
cp: error reading '/var/lib/lxc/my-couch2/rootfs/home/foo/couchdb/couchdb/data/.shards/40000000-5fffffff/bar2.1533443496_design/mrview/54f171fe1f24ac4eb52ac24c85f9d8fc.view': Input/output error
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/backups.html):

> To ensure reliability of backups, it is recommended that you back up secondary indexes (stored under data/.shards) prior to backing up the main database files (stored under data/shards as well as the system-level databases at the parent data/ directory). This is because CouchDB will automatically handle views/secondary indexes that are slightly out of date by updating them on the next read access, but views or secondary indexes that are newer than their associated databases will trigger a full rebuild of the index. This can be a very costly and time-consuming operation, and can impact your ability to recover quickly in a disaster situation.

So, AFAIK it's a temporary file. Is there a way to rebuild this file by using CouchDB itself, so that we can both fix the file on the server and are able to make a backup normally?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on [apache/couchdb/issues](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2032). Regarding to the response, I backed up the erroneous file and triggered all views in the database `bar2`. That file is restored and everything seems to work correctly.